# How to set up push notifications based on location in iOS?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, ios10

I'm writing an app in which users create postings which are geotagged and are stored on Firebase database. I want other users to be notified of these postings if they are in a nearby vicinity.

**EDIT**

How should I go about making such a function?

*NOTE: I have managed to setup my app with push notifications and I have hooked it up to Firebase to receive "Message" from Firebase*

**Aditionally**

I want users to tailor the notifications they receive to their prefrences based on features in the postings

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What does this mean exactly "how to go about receiving notifications based on users location".  A script running in the background on the device is never ever ever a good idea, not that its even actually really possible in iOS. Are you asking how to receive a push, how to send a push, how to register for location and send a push based on that, how to register for location and receive pushes based on that? Irrespective of the question, a script running in the background is not the solution. Or are you talking about a script running on a server?

Comment: Im sorry for the misleading "script solution" i was suggesting. I simply like to know if anyone knows the steps involved going about making this feature. I edited the post. Any source of information which i could read would be also very helpful. Thanks

Comment: use User Segments?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for geofencing!

Basically, you can set up a geofence which you can think of as an area that, if the user's device enters that area, triggers an action like sending a local iOS notification. It's nice in that it works even if your app is in the background. That said, it's probably a bit too much of a weighty topic to get into here, but there's a pretty good [geofencing tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/136165/core-location-geofencing-tutorial) over on RayWenderlich.com that you should probably check out.

What you can do is have your app read in relevant locations from the database and then create a bunch of geofences to trigger these notifications when the user enters these locations. One important note, however, is that iOS limits you to 20 active geofences at a time, so you may need to do some work to determine what geofences are most relevant to your user whenever they use your app.